# Formula not working as expected

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I have the following formula:

`AND($Permission.NMEC_EE2020 = FALSE,RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Population_Project_Res',NM_Ineligibility_Date__c <= NM_Initial_Implementation_End_Date_EI__c)`

The last of the three conditionals is where I have the issue.  The intent is to accept a date value for `NM_Ineligibility_Date__c` greater than or equal to `NM_Initial_Implementation_End_Date_EI__c`.  However, users are forced to enter a date greater than and does not accept equal to`NM_Initial_Implementation_End_Date_EI__c`.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that a checkbox formula or a Validation Rule?. Keep in mind that Validation Rules shows the error when the formula evaluates to "true", so according to yours, it will show an error if `NM_ineligibility_date__c <= NM_Initial_Implementation_End_Date_EI__c` as long as EE2020 is false and RecordType is Population_Project_Res.

Answer (score 0):

Your third conditional is written as to evaluate to true if `NM_Ineligibility_Date__c`is less or equal (`<=`) to `NM_Initial_Implementation_End_Date_EI__c`.

Less or equal leads to the problem you described, as both dates being equal evaluates to true. If you want to allow equal to also be accepted, change the comparison to just less than `<` instead of less or equals `<=`.